# perl -pe to manipulate filenames

Tags: perl, shell

I was trying to do some quick filename cleanup at the shell (zsh, if it matters). Renaming files. (I'm using `cp` instead of `mv` just to be safe)

```
foreach f (\#*.ogg)
  cp $f `echo $f | perl -pe 's/\#\d+ (.+)$/"\1"/'`
end
```

Now, I know there are tools to do stuff like this, but for personal interest I'm wondering how I can do it this way. Right now, I get an error:

```
cp: target `When.ogg"' is not a directory
```

Where 'When.ogg' is the last part of the filename. I've tried adding quotes (see above) and escaping the spaces, but nonetheless this is what I get.

Is there a reason I can't use the output of s perl pmr=;omrt as the final argument to another command line tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need in bash, hope it's good for zsh too.

```
cp "$f" "`echo $f | perl -pe 's/\#\d+ (.+)$/\1/'`"
```

If the filename contains spaces, you also have quote the second argument of cp.

Comment: Ah, that was it. The double quotes around the $f aren't necessary, but the double quotes around the entire backtick part are. I don't really understand why putting them out there works but putting them inside (around the \1 in my original) doesn't, but I'm just happy to know.

Comment: The double quotes around the $f are necessary if there is a space in the filenames.  Also, double quotes around the echo's $f are also necessary if you have 2 consecutive spaces in the filenames.

Comment: @jfgagne: thanks for mentioning consecutive spaces, haven't thought about it.

Comment: zsh handles `$f` without quotes, but the bourne shell would need `"$f"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a space in the file names being processed, so each of your cp command lines evaluates to something like

```
cp \#nnnn When.Ogg When.ogg
```

When the cp command sees more than two arguments, the last one must be a target directory name for all the files to be copied to - hence the error message. Because your source filename (`$f`) contains a space it is being treated as two arguments - cp sees *three* args, rather than the two you intend.

If you put double quotes around the *first* $f that should prevent the two 'halves' of the name from being treated as separate file names:

```
cp "$f" `echo ...
```

Comment: Afraid not, I added the double quotes around the first argument but it's still giving me the same errors.

Comment: @hsiu try replacing cp with echo, see what's going on?

Comment: yi_H got it below, the double quotes needed to be around the whole backticked part - having perl put them around the filenames didn't work. Don't understand it, but I think I can run with it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I often use

```
dir /b ... | perl -nle"$o=$_; s/.../.../; $n=$_; rename $o,$n if !-e $n"
```

The `-l` chomps the input.

The `-e` check is to avoid accidentally renaming all the files to one name. I've done that a couple of times.

In bash (and I'm guessing zsh), that would be

```
foreach f (...)
   echo "$f" | perl -nle'$o=$_; s/.../.../; $n=$_; rename $o,$n if !-e $n'
end
```

or

```
find -name '...'  -maxdepth 1 \
   | perl -nle'$o=$_; s/.../.../; $n=$_; rename $o,$n if !-e $n'
```

or

```
find -name '...'  -maxdepth 1 -exec \
   perl -e'for (@ARGV) {
      $o=$_; s/.../.../; $n=$_;
      rename $o,$n if !-e $n;
   }' {} +
```

The last supports file names with newlines in them.